# How Java & GraalJs ScriptEngine interact with variables

Tags: java, jsr223, scriptengine, graaljs

Now, I'm trying execute Javascript in Java application via GraalJS. the following is my code:

```java
import javax.script.*;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

public class ScriptExec {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws ScriptException {
        System.setProperty("polyglot.engine.WarnInterpreterOnly", "false");

        ScriptEngineManager manager = new ScriptEngineManager();
        ScriptEngine engine = manager.getEngineByName("js");
        Bindings bindings = engine.createBindings();

        // variables
        int num = 9;
        String hello = "bye";
        String[] strings = new String[]{"a", "string", "array"};
        List<String> stringList = List.of("a", "string", "list");
        Map<String, Object> kvs = Map.of("a", "b", "object", "...", "map", "container");

        bindings.put("num", num); 
        bindings.put("hello", hello);
        bindings.put("strings", strings);
        bindings.put("stringList", stringList);
        bindings.put("kvs", kvs);

        engine.setBindings(bindings, ScriptContext.ENGINE_SCOPE);
        String js = """
                console.log(num)
                console.log(hello)
                console.log(JSON.stringify(strings))
                console.log(JSON.stringify(stringList))
                console.log(JSON.stringify(kvs))
                for(let str in strings) {
                    console.log('str: ' + str)
                }
                for(let k in kvs) {
                    console.log('key: ' + k)
                }
                """;
        engine.eval(js);
    }
}
```

- and the console output is:

```
9
bye
{}
{}
{}
```

as you see, only the integer type and String variables are bind successfully.

- JDK version: 17
- GraalJS dependencies:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.graalvm.js</groupId>
    <artifactId>js</artifactId>
    <version>22.3.2</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.graalvm.js</groupId>
    <artifactId>js-scriptengine</artifactId>
    <version>22.3.2</version>
</dependency>
```

**1. what is going on array, list and map type variables?
2. how to solve this?**

Comment: ok, i find help [here](https://www.graalvm.org/sdk/javadoc/org/graalvm/polyglot/Context.html)

Comment: How did that help? What changes did you have to make to get your original code working? You can post an answer to your own question if you have a solution to your problem.

Answer (score 1):

ok, i find the answer from [here](https://www.graalvm.org/sdk/javadoc/org/graalvm/polyglot/Context.html)

```java
import org.graalvm.polyglot.Context;
import org.graalvm.polyglot.Value;

import javax.script.ScriptException;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

public class ScriptExec {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws ScriptException {
        System.setProperty("polyglot.engine.WarnInterpreterOnly", "false");

        // Get a polyglot context for Graal guest languages(here is JavaScript)
        Context context = Context.newBuilder("js")
                .allowAllAccess(true) // if not allow, you still cannot access the array/list/object members
                .build();

        // Variables
        var num = 9;
        var hello = "bye";
        var strings = new String[]{"a", "string", "array"};
        var stringList = List.of("a", "string", "list");
        var kvs = new HashMap<>(Map.of("a", "ok", "object", 1, "container", "..."));

        // Pass java variable to GraalJS polyglot context
        Value bindings = context.getBindings("js");

        bindings.putMember("num", num);
        bindings.putMember("hello", hello);
        bindings.putMember("strings", strings);
        bindings.putMember("stringList", stringList);
        bindings.putMember("kvs", kvs);

        // JavaScript code
        var script = """
                console.log(num)
                console.log(hello)
                console.log(JSON.stringify(strings))
                console.log(JSON.stringify(stringList))
                console.log(JSON.stringify(kvs.toString()))
                for(let index in strings) {
                    console.log("index:", index, ", value:", strings[index])
                }
                for(let k in kvs) {
                    console.log(k)
                }
                """;

        // Evaluate the code
        context.eval("js", script);

        // Release resources
        context.close();
    }
}
```

the above code, without create a ScriptEngine explicitly. the polyglot context of Graal does the work.

also can create ScriptEngine firstly, then pass the special polyglot context to it. `special` means host resources access controlling config (allowXXX...).

if something new, post later